# Ввод и передача аргументов в запущенную команду bash

Tags: python, bash

Необходимо подключиться к серверу и передавать ему ответы на его вопросы, в зависимости от их содержания.
Я написал такой код.

```
import subprocess


dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
data = subprocess.run(["nc", "<ip>", "<port>"], text=True)
if data in dict:
    answer1 = subprocess.run('input2')
    print(answer2)
else:
    answer2 = subprocess.run('input2')
    print(answer2)
```

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Первая команда запускается и я вижу ответ от сервера с вопросом, но т.к. эта команда не завершает выполнение, то мои другие команды не запускаются и я не могу ответить серверу. Я не должен разрывать соединение, но при этом у меня не получается передавать команды после запуска первой. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Многопоточный режим устроит?

Comment: И, кстати, у вас опечатка в `anser2` - это не мешает?

Comment: @Сергей спасибо, опечатку исправил. Многопоточный режим устроит.

Comment: Так  попробуйте. <https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/threading.html#module-threading>. Обычно его рекомендуют при операциях с блокирующим вводом-выводом (при неблокирующем - асинхронный режим советуют).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условно как-то так может выглядеть относительно вашего кода, насколько я его понял:

```
from threading import Thread

def thread_work (list1, text):
    # Заменить на то, что нужно
    pass 
         
def thread_work1 ():
    answer1=(input('input2'))
    print (answer1)

def thread_work2 ():
    answer2=(input('input2'))
    print (answer2)    

thr0 = Thread(target=thread_work, args=(["nc", "<ip>", "<port>"], True,))
thr1 = Thread(target=thread_work1)
thr2 = Thread(target=thread_work2)
```

Если нужен обмен данными или блокирующий доступ, то доп.механизмы могут быть нужны.

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).